# how to cascade GroupSequenceProvider to member List?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Hi say I have sample bean called car and I want to redefine its validation sequence:

```
@GroupSequenceProvider(value = CarSequenceProvider.class)
public class Car{
   @NotNull(groups = {groupOne.class})
   private Boolean isGood;

   @Valid
   private List<Driver> drivers;

   // getter/setter
}
```

this is my driver class

```
public class Driver{

  @NotEmpty(groups = {groupTwo.class})
  private List<String> skills;    

  //getter/setter
}
```

and here goes my sequence provider:

```
public class CarSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<Car>{

  @Override
  public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(Car car) {
    List<Class<?>> sequence = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    sequence.add(Car.class);
    sequence.add(groupOne.class);

    if(car != null && car.IsGood()){
      sequence.add(groupTwo.class);
    }
}
```

Basically I only want All drivers skills not to be empty if the car is good. What is happening right now is that @notEmpty never gets called because my sequence redefinition is not cascaded to Driver List. Is it possible to make it cascade then?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> Here @ConvertGroup comes into play which allows you during cascaded
>   validation to use a different group than the originally requested one.

Is that annotation you tried

Source: [example-group-conversion-dedault-to-driver-checks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#example-group-conversion-dedault-to-driver-checks)

Comment: Hi Yes I understand that convertGroup will suffice in my example. However, what if I have a sequence with many groups in car class provided by the provider and I simply want that sequence to be inherited by my driver class, is there any way to achieve that?